Two gui TTY at startup, how to disable on of them?
I have installed ubuntu 24.04 recently, and I noticed that by default my GUI is on TTY2, but weirdly, TTY1 also has a gui open, waiting for me to login. TTY3 to TTY7 are normal command prompts.
Is there a way to disable one of the guis ?
Thank you all for your help, this forum is a great ressource.
My setup :
Ubuntu 24.04
Razer Blade base model 2019
Intel integrated graphics + NVidia gtx 2060
Using the NVidia 535 drive (not the one with the open kernel)

There is a way to change all that, but it becomes highly technical. You are advised to leave this configuration the way the distribution has set it up.
Already since quite some time, Ubuntu is set up to have GDM running on TTY1, and the user session on TTY2. Many years ago, a single tty, TTY7, was used to run xorg and the desktop environment.

Thank you, as a powerless-user, i'll leave that be. I was looking for a solution to freezes I randomly encounter, but I'll look elsewhere!

Thanks, I did not know that this was standard procedure. Have a nice day!
